# How does google generate the formatted list of links under the #1 result on a google search?

Tags: seo

If you google a specific entity, occasionally the website listed first is given a little listing of content, sort of like a mini site-map that the user can click on to navigate the linked site, bypassing the home page.

My question is this: Can I control this mini-sitemap when I am PR1? If so, how do I do so? I'm trying to build a list of relevant links so users can more effectively hit my site, but I'm not sure where to go about doing this.

Help?

Comment: Keep an eye on tech such as Yahoo Search Monkey and Google Rich Snippets. They won't give you full control, but may allow you to expose some links the engines consider sensible to expose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot turn this on. Google decides this on their own wheter or not to generate them and for which search terms. If you sign up for the [google webmasters](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) you can see the status (if google has generated some for your site) and read more about their background.

Answer (score 2):

They are called Sitelinks - there's [a FAQ entry about them here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334).

You can't control them (except to remove ones you don't like) - the FAQ says *"At the moment, sitelinks are completely automated."*

Answer (score 2):

Google generates the sitelinks itself, but only for certain sites.  As for how it determines which sites get it and which don't, I'm not really sure, but I suspect it has something to do with the pagerank of the site and the amount of content you have.

For a while, I had sitelinks for my site (PR4 with about 40,000 pages indexed in Google) but then a while later, they went away.  In my case it generated sitelinks for the main tabs on the site, probably because they are in the header navigation and therefore on every single page near the top of the page.

The only control you have over them is you can use the Google webmaster tools to remove sitelinks that you don't like, but you can't change the existing ones or suggest new ones.